# PageFactory class of selenium and its working when used with FindBy Annotation

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a question on how the PageFactory.initElements method of Selenium webdriver works when I use FindBy annotation

I have a snippet of code like this

```
Class PageObject {
@FindBy(id = "username")
private WebElement userName;
@FindBy(id = "password")
private WebElement passWord;
private WebDriver driver;
private String url = "http://www.loginpage.com";

public PageObject() {
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
 }

 void load() {
   this.driver.get(url);
  }
 }

 class TestClass {
   public void testMethod() {
       PageObject po = new PageObject();
       po.load();
   }
}
```

If I read documentation of the PageFactory.initElements method, it says - Instantiate an instance of the given class, and set a lazy proxy for each of the WebElement and List fields that have been declared, assuming that the field name is also the HTML element's "id" or "name".

My question here is  when I create the object of the page in the test class, it fires the constructor of the page object and initializes the webelements using PageFactory. But what it would initialize to? I navigate to the page only after I construct the page object, using the load method. What would the PageFactory initialize my WebElements to when the page is not yet available. How does it work. Can somebody please help me understand this

Regards
Gauri

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what happens: When you call `initElements`, the `PageObjectFactory` scans your `PageObject` for fields of the type `WebElement`. For each `WebElement` field that your page object has, it creates a proxy object. That proxy object stores the locator of the `WebElement` (the value of the `@FindBy` annotation). The proxy is then assigned to the field.

Later, when your code actually accesses the field, instead of a `WebElement` object, you retrieve the proxy. Remember that the proxy object "knows" the locator of the `WebElement` it represents. Now the proxy actually tries to locate that locator on the current page, and returns the actual `WebElement` if it was found.

So, in your example, as long as you don't work with the `userName` or `passWord` fields, they won't be actually *located*. That means, that for example you wouldn't get a `NoSuchElementException`, even if the locators were wrong, unless you actually work with those elements.

So to answer your question: It doesn't matter that at the time when the `PageObject` is initialized the driver hasn't navigated anywhere yet, as the creation of the proxy objects doesn't actually *locate* them.

Comment: is there a tutorial to create something like this? I’m working on a project that needs to do something similar.